# Очистка listview и SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, android-studio, listview, cursoradaper

Не получается очистить listview в момент, когда захожу на это активити. Уже столько всего перепробовал.

```
    package com.example.covenant.optimization;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ListView;

import static com.example.covenant.optimization.FilterActivity.str;

public class FindModelsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView lv_findModels;
    SimpleCursorAdapter sCursorAdapter;
    String[] from;
    int[] to;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_find_models);
        setTitle("Подходящие модели");

        lv_findModels = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_findModels);

        showFindModels();
    }


    //==============================================================================================

    public void showFindModels() {
        DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = database.query(
                "tablets",              //таблица
                null,                   //столбцы
                "Бренд = ?",            //строка условия WHERE
                new String[] {str},     //массив аргументов для selectionм
                null,                   //группировка
                null,                   //
                null                    //сортировка
        );
//        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tablets WHERE Бренд = ?", new String[]{str}); 

        from = new String[]{cursor.getColumnName(1), cursor.getColumnName(3), cursor.getColumnName(2)};//массив столбцов, поля которых собираемся отображать
        to = new int[]{R.id.tvName, R.id.tvPrice, R.id.tvModel};                                    //Массив View-компонентов для отображения этих стобцов
        sCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item_listview, cursor, from, to, 0);//Создал адаптер и настроил ему кастомный вид
        sCursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        lv_findModels.setAdapter(sCursorAdapter);                                                   //Повесил адаптер
        dbHelper.close();                                                                           //Закрыл подключение к БД

    }
}
```

Comment: lv_findModels.setAdapter(null);

Comment: pavlofff делал, не помогает.

Comment: отключение адаптера от списка не может не очистить его. Видимо ваша проблема не в очистке, а в условии, когда вызывать метод `showFindModels()`, который и заполняет список, но ответить на этот вопрос по предоставленным вами сведениям нельзя (в частности, когда именно должны появляться данные в списке вы не рассказали)

Comment: Из кода видно что они должны появляться на onCreate

Comment: тогда где он должен очищаться, из вашего вопроса не ясно, какая у вас проблема

Comment: @Evgeny, мой старый помутневший хрустальный шар говорит, что у Вас список заполняется не теми данными и Вы думаете что они там остаются с прошлого запуска активности, так?

Comment: Woesss, да, все верно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема Ваша кроется в использовании статик поля `FilterActivity.str`. Я незнаю как и где оно у Вас изменяется, но явно не вовремя. Возможно Вы делаете это в фоновом потоке, но статические поля не потоко-безопасны и другой поток может не увидеть изменений сразу. Из-за этого запрос в базу идёт тот же и возвращаются те же данные.
И вообще-то обмен данными между компонентами приложения через статик поля изначально плохая затея - для этого нужно использовать экстра-данные интента.